# Unity collision not being detected

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am learning to create a simple fps game in unity the problem is that the collision does not update itself for example  initially when my player is on the ground console prints "floor" by "Debug.log(collision.gameObject)" but when it intersects other objects such as a cube console will print out "cube" but when I walk away from it , console does not change back to "floor" Why????

I am using transform.translate to move and jump and using method OnCollisionEnter for collision detection

Comment: Explore: CollisionStay, CollissionEnter, CollisonExit. Does the object ever leave the floor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnCollisionEnter` is triggered only when object *enters* the collider.

A) Make a list of all encountered objects by adding them when `OnCollisionEnter` happens and removing when `OnCollisionExit` happens. Then whenever you need to make sure you are on "floor" check it in the list.

B) Use `OnCollisionStay` and every frame you will be notified if you are touching the "floor".

Answer (score 1):

Remember one thing, the other object you want to collide with need to have a collider component asigned, make sure of it. Join this with the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to verify collision. 
Here on simple example:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col){
        if (col.gameObject){
            Debug.Log("Object name : "+ col.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
```