# Unity 3D colision of objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3D game that is generated randomly when you hit play. The thing is that objects don't generate with collision and characters start moving through walls. What is the necessary code for an object to be generated with collision in C# ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity collision not being detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353310/unity-collision-not-being-detected)

Comment: 1. UnityScript is a different language than C# 2. What does *"objects don't generate colision"* mean? Do they have colliders and/or rigidbodies assigned to them?

Comment: You need a collider component on the objects for collisions to work. One of the objects also need a rigidbody. Show your code and more context if you want more help than that.

Comment: In abouth 2 hours I will get home and post the code . Thank you fore your reply and sorry for the rong tag I am new to this

Answer (score 1):

Ok if I have read your question correctly, you are auto generating random meshes for you game but they do not yet have colliders on them. To generate a collider for an object in c# see the following example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AddComponentExample : MonoBehaviour
{
   void Start( )
   {
      SphereCollider sc = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider> as SphereCollider;
   }
}
```

You need to add a collider component to the gameobject you are generating. The one you choose depends on the mesh you created, so if you are generating cube meshes choose a box collider.

If you are creating your own meshes instead of primitives that are more complex then you can apply a "MeshCollider". But be warned if you are creating your own mesh at run time you may get some unusual artefacts.

Hope that helps

Comment: It's better to use the Generic syntax, if the type is spelled wrong you'll get an error when compiling, whereas the string syntax won't.

  `SphereCollider sc = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>( ) as SphereCollider;`

Comment: You are absolutely correct sir, in fact the string format is now deprecated in Unity 5 and I will adjust my answer :)

Comment: Thank you all . I know the question was dumb and I forgot to post some code because I am new to all of this . You all helped a little . I will keep you informed when I apply your code if it worked